# ubuntu kernel and INT 13H interrupt

Tags: application-development

I'm new of this Ubuntu mailing list.

My question is addressed to the kernel ubuntu developers.

I use ubuntu and the grub 2 boot loader.

The question is:

I'd like to know if the Ubuntu kernel uses BIOS/UEFI services, in particular the INT 13H interrupt, or if the kernel is BIOS indipendent ?

In this last case in which a way Ubuntu treats the low-level disk services ?
That is in which way Ubuntu intercept the call and passes it to the operating system's native disk I/O mechanism bypassing BIOS routines for the low-level disk reading/writing access ?

My understanding is that the Linux kernel typically doesn't use BIOS services for disk I/O since it's running in protected mode.
However i don't know if could be there some edge cases where this isn't true and could happen that the kernel executes writing operations into the filesystem of the plugged disk.

So i thought to write you to ask tips to a kernel developer authoritative about this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regatds.

Vincenzo Di Salvo

Comment: Are you kidding? Nobody uses int13H nowadays.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057670/how-to-write-on-hard-disk-with-bios-interrupt-13h PS most of us (if not all of us) are not kernel developers here. Simply enthusiasts for the most part.